# method Inheritance in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

I am working on a code that I am not sure to understand well. I have a class `ChildA`  that inherits from `MotherA`. 
In a `ChildA`, I do :

```
MotherA *theObj ;
[theObj method1];
[theObj method2];
```

theObj recognizes `method1`, but not `method2`, whereas both are defined in `ChildA`, I don't understand why. (Tell me if my question is not clear).
Thank you !

Comment: Are `method1` and `method2` both defined in `MotherA` and overridden in `ChildA`? Or are they defined only in `ChildA`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `theObj` is an instance of `MotherA` then it responds only to those methods defined on `MotherA`.

If it is an instance of `ChildA` then it responds to the union of those methods defined on `MotherA` and `ChildA`. Anywhere that the two define the same method, calls to that instance will go to the implementation from `ChildA`. The implementation of `ChildA` can internally defer to the `MotherA` implementation by calling `super`.

Comment: The `ChildA` implementation of the method will  only be run on instances of `ChildA` if my understanding is correct. When running a method against an instance of `MotherA` it will still run the `Mother1` implementation of it.

Comment: Ah sorry, I understand now :D

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't make much sense:

```
MotherA *theObj ; [theObj method1]; [theObj method2];
```

Shouldn't that be `[super method1]`?  Also `theObj == nil` so nothing will happen anyway.

You cannot call `[super method2]` if `method2` is only defined in the subclass (`ChildA`) and not the superclass (`MotherA`).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a class...

```
@interface MotherA: NSObject

- (void)method1;

@end
```

and a subclass...

```
@interface ChildA: MotherA

- (void)method2;

@end
```

Then you can only call `method2` on instances of `ChildA`. `method1` can be called on instances of `ChildA` and `MotherA`.

A subclass inherits the methods from its superclass. Not the other way around.

What you are doing (I think) is expecting a superclass to inherit the methods of its subclass.